# Не могу развернуть WAR в Tomcat

Tags: java-ee, servlet, maven, tomcat

Здравствуйте. Вчера я начал знакомится с обычными `Java Servlets` и контейнером `Tomcat`. Работаю я в IntelliJ IDEA 15.
В чем проблема: 
Не могу сделать деплой проекта в Tomcat. 
В общем у меня есть класс `MyServlet` (с минимальным сервлетом), `web.xml`(указал в нём сервлет), pom.xml (конфигурационный файл Maven). 
В pom.xml я указал что собирать будем в WAR-архив.

Это мой web.xml: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собираю в WAR (mvn clean package) — получаю WAR:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перемещаю мой WAR-ник в %TOMCAT_HOME%/webapps, запускаю startup.bat, localhost:8080/TestServlet/hello — 404 от Tomcat...
Запускаю со среды (Run "Tomcat 7.0.65").. Также ничего, все тот же 404. Если переместить без WAR-ника (исходники) — все работает, причем прекрасно. Вроде по шагам все расписал. Я не пойму в чем проблема :( Гугл выдал, что нужно сделать WAR-ник и переместить его в %TOMCAT_HOME%/webapps, Tomcat сам его достанет.

Логи:
**localhost_access_log.2015-12-08:**

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [08/Dec/2015:15:13:08 +0300] "GET /TestServlet/hello HTTP/1.1" 404 985
```

**localhost.2015-12-08:**

```
Dec 08, 2015 3:12:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Dec 08, 2015 3:12:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Dec 08, 2015 3:12:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@269372d7')
```

Я в этом не силен, только учусь, возможно пропустил где-то мелочь.

P.S. — Уже и на исходниках не работает :(

Answer (score 2):

По умолчанию tomcat предоставляет контекст равный имени war'ника. Т.е. надо стучаться не в `localhost:8080/TestServlet/hello` а в `localhost:8080/TestServlet-1.0/hello`. Для того, чтобы запускать через IDE тебе нужно создать отдельную конфигурацию. [Здесь](http://devcolibri.com/4249) отличное руководство для начинающих. Единственное, там не указано, что по умолчанию даётся корневой контекст (переопределить можно во вкладке `deployment`), т.е. стучаться придётся в `localhost:8080/hello`. Плюс к тому, ты в `web.xml` указал спецификацию сервлетов **3.1**, а tomcat версии 7 поддерживает только **3.0**